# How to bind the selectedvalue (header) of a TabControl to a property on a view model

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol and inside a collection of tabitems.  I want to bind the selectedvalue's header to a property in my viewmodel so I know when a tab is selected.

My thought process led me to try the following:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl" SelectedValue.Header="{Binding SelectedTab}">
```

This does not work - probably because the SelectedValue is not of type HeaderedContentControl (although it always will be in this instance).

Is it possible to cast in XAML inline so that I can do the above?

Or can anyone suggest another way to effectively achieve the same kind of thing elegantly?  I do not want to change the code-behind of the XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code works for me...

**C#:**

```
public class MyTabItemData     {
     public int Index { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
} 

public class MyTabControlViewModel {
     public List<MyTabItemData> TabItemsData { 
         get {
             //return list of tab items data.
         } 
     }

     public ICollectionView TabItemsDataView {
          get {
              return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TabItemsData);
          }
     }

     public MyTabItemData MyCurrentTabItemData {
          get {
              return TabItemsDataView.CurrentItem as MyTabItemData;
          }
     }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemsDataView}" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
     ....
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<TabControl x:Name="TabControl" SelectedValue.Header="{Binding SelectedTab}">`
bind to SelectedValue and use a converter to get the Header like so:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTab, Converter={StaticResource TabItemToHeader}}">
```

Your converter could look like

```
public class TabItemToHeaderConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((TabItem)value).Header
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Header`is no attached property, so you cant bind to it through `SelectedValue.Header="{}"`.

Comment: Yes I had thought of this way but thought there would be something like an inline XAML cast (which I don't think there is).

Comment: The converter isn't necessary, this works all right: Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Header, ElementName=xxx}"